# Spring Boot + AngularJS routing not working

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, routes

Spring Boot + AngularJS routing not working
[image]

Comment: could you please test with template `template:'<b>Hello</b>'`, please let me know the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change `template` to `templateUrl`. `template` is used when you are writing html code inside `when` like this:

```
template:'<b>Hello</b>'
```

templateUrl is used for providing html file as string URL.

```
templateUrl:'filmList.html'
```